# How to specify a database when accessing arangodb using curl?

Tags: arangodb

I'm new to arangodb and went through the site's CRUD tutorial. I don't see how to select from collections not in the default _system database. Is there a way to tell curl?
Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curl command would look like this:

```
curl --data @- -X POST --dump - http://0.0.0.0:8529/_db/mydb/_api/cursor <<< '{ "query" : "FOR u IN mycollection FILTER u.name == \"Hase\" RETURN u" }'
```

**mydb** is the database you want to use.

The pattern extends to nearly all REST APIs:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/databases/